# Get a field value from an nid

Tags: entities, nodes

I have the nid of a node and I want to get one of its fields' value. Right now I am doing a `node_load` on the nid and then using `field_get_items` to get the value. Is this the right way? It seems kind of convoluted, and inefficient to load the whole node object for what is essentially a few joins for a single field.

Is there a way I can just specificy the node id and the field, and get its value?

Comment: I've updated the answer in the duplicate with some code, that's about the neatest way there is to do it I think. You'll still have to run `field_get_items()` on the resulting node objects but at least you can avoid the heavy DB overhead

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks for your expertise! :)